# How to make PoEdit correctly parse custom "ngettext" implementation?

Tags: php, localization, internationalization, gettext, poedit

I've coded a gettext wrapper that makes the whole process of l10n a little bit simpler but somehow I can't get PoEdit to correctly identify and parse plural version calls to the function. This is what I originally had:

```
_e(array('%d house', '%d houses'), 5);
```

But that doesn't work at all, PoEdit picks nothing at all. I also tried:

```
_e('%d house', '%d houses', 5);
```

This time PoEdit catches the `%d house` but not the plural form of `%d houses`, however if I try exactly the same but with a `ngettext()` call it works perfectly, both the singular and plural forms are identified:

```
ngettext('%d house', '%d house', 5);
```

I've correctly (?) added the `_e` keyword to the project settings, but it doesn't pick up plural variations. I've also noticed that PoEdit only has `_`, `gettext` and `gettext_noop` as the default keyworks to pick up, there is no reference whatsoever to the `ngettext`, `dngettext` or `dcngettext` functions but it can still correctly pick up the `ngettext` calls... This makes me wonder if PoEdit has hardcoded the `ngettext` keyword - that would be really sad.

Anyway, is there any way to make PoEdit (or any other similar app), correctly parse custom functions?

Comment: Do you have at least Poedit 1.3.0?

Comment: @Alexandre: Poedit 1.4.6 (Windows).

Comment: I found this link (http://www.devcomments.com/Zend_Translate-plural-forms-and-poedit-at188420.htm) it seems that it isn't possible. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: According to the [xgettext documentation](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/xgettext-Invocation.html), you have to add the `_e` keyword to the project (which will take the first argument only) or `_e:1,2` which will take the first and second argument and interpret them as plural forms.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found the solution, the keyword has to be defined with the following expression:

```
_e:1,2
```

Source: http://osdir.com/ml/editors.poedit.user/2008-05/msg00012.html

Comment: Yes, as documented in `xgettext` docs... Poedit just calls `xgettext`.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you need to do both things above.

- Define the keyword like '_e:1,2'
  AND
- Add the plural form 
  nplurals=2; plural=n != 1;

to the catalogue settings

Comment: Plural forms vary from language to language, and still isn't related to the problem.

Comment: ngettext only supports two plural forms anyway, so what's your point?

Comment: Actually, no. See the first (and only) example on http://php.net/manual/en/function.ngettext.php: "1 okno", "2 okna" and "5 oken".

Comment: "Anyway, is there any way to make PoEdit (or any other similar app), correctly parse custom functions?"  PoEdit works fine for me with a custom plural function. I defined the keywords as Deckard mentioned (or as defined in section 5.1.6 of this page http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/xgettext-Invocation.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, it is very easy to setup. Just follow the steps below:

Menu: Catalog -> Settings will open the Settings dialog. On the Project Info tab you will find "**Plural Forms**" at the bottom. Just copy & paste the following line in this field:

```
nplurals=2; plural=n != 1;
```

That will fix the problem perfectly. I didn't even had to rescan the sources; the correct lines automatically appeared in the PoEditer.

Comment: I don't think you have understood my question.