# Gettext placeholders

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext, placeholder

I am building a multilingual application in PHP + CodeIgniter. I have settled upon using gettext for UI text translation, and so far it has proven efficient and easy to work with.

But now I am facing something really annoying: the `gettext()` function only accepts one parametre, while I'd like a printf-like behaviour that I get from Zend Framework's gettext adapter, where I can use `%1$s`, `%2$s` etc. as placeholders and then specify the replacement strings as additional parametres to Zend view's `translate()` function.

I do not wish to ditch gettext due to the easy translation management with .po files and poEdit (I can get it updated with a single click, after all). What are my options?

I have already tried writing a helper to interact with gettext: run the first argument through gettext and then run strtr on the resulting string. Are there any other/better approaches you would recommend?

Comment: I do realize that you said you don't want to ditch gettext, but you should be aware that you *can* use Zend_Translate and CI together without too much trouble.  [The manual says](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.adapter.html) that it can read `.mo` files.  I'm not sure how those differ from `.po` files, thus the reason why I'm posting this as a comment instead of an answer.  The manual does say that "POEdit" works with that format.

Comment: `.mo` is what `.po` becomes after it's compiled. Gettext reads `.mo`, but `.po` is human-readable and that's what you edit :). Yes, using Zend_Translate is definitely an option to consider.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's quite simple actually, you define a variadic function like this:

```
function myGettext($id)
{
    return vsprintf(gettext($id), array_slice(func_get_args(), 1));
}
```

Now doing `myGettext('%u %s in a %s', 3, 'monkeys', 'tree')` will return the expected string with the placeholders replaced by the remaining arguments. You obviously also need to implement a plural aware function that calls `ngettext()` instead.

Regarding poEdit, you have to modify the keywords it searches for, it's been a while since I last used it but it was quite simple, the only problem I faced was identifying keywords for plural support ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393139/how-to-make-poedit-correctly-parse-custom-ngettext-implementation)).

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is more or less what my helper does, but the code is simpler (a single line vs. four, hehe). poEdit indeed has the possibility to define the keywords - this is how I pick up the translatable strings in Zend Framework's `translate`, `setLabel` and `setDescription` functions :). Thanks, I like your approach.

Comment: it wasn't exactly a "problem", but yes, I changed my helper to what you suggested and not only does it work like a charm, but I'm also lovin' the amount of code it requires :D. Thanks again.

Comment: @mingos: Oh, great. I'm glad I could be of some help. ;)