# PHP gettext translate available string part

Tags: php, translation, gettext

I have a website where and we have some descriptions saved in english. we want to translate them in other languages like french, chinese etc.

My string is

```
Call Consumption period before the 2015-01-27
Maintenance of Phone Numbers Quantity 10
```

My translation is like this

```
msgid "Call Consumption period before the"
msgstr "Período de consumo de llamadas antes de la"

msgid "Maintenance of Phone Numbers Quantity"
msgstr "Mantenimiento de los números de teléfono Cantidad Wrong"
```

I want to translate it and ignore date and number part how can I do this.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445815/gettext-placeholders

Answer (score 0):

To translate the date,

For example you can put a switch case like this

```
switch ($lang) {
case 'en':
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'en_CA.UTF-8');
    echo strftime("%B %e, %G");
    break;
case 'fr':
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_CA.UTF-8');
    echo strftime("%e %B %G");
    break;
```

}

You look what language are the website and displays the date based on the iso.

It's just an idea i don't know if it's the better solution.