# Error, expects exactly 1 argument, 2 given, in a laravel9 model

Tags: php, laravel-9

In my system there is a part to list competitions. When a competition signup opens later then today there should be like this:
"Signup opens 2022-08-29"
The program row in the app/models/competition.php looks like this:

```
252        elseif($this->status == 'not_opened'):
253            return _('Signup opens %s', $this->signups_opening_date);
```

But when I open the list I got an error as this:

```
(ArgumentCountError(code: 0): _() expects exactly 1 argument, 2 given at /Users/ralph/laravel9-final/Webshooter_web_Laravel9/app/Models/Competition.php:253)
```

It suppose to get the date from the database and show after Signup opens.....

What can be wrong?

But...
In other places the date appears as here:

```
<tr>
   <td width="40%">{{_('Opens for signup')}}</td>
   <td><% competitions.competition.signups_opening_date %></td>
</tr>
```

Shows like this:
Opens for signup    2022-08-22

Comment: put `sprintf('Signup opens %s', $this->signups_opening_date)` into _() in your first case

Comment: The error describes exactly the problem - [`gettext()` (and the shortcut version `_()`) only accepts 1 parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445815/gettext-placeholders).  If you want to use substitutions you will need another solution - eg maybe [Laravel's own localisation features](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/localization).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gettext placeholders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445815/gettext-placeholders)

Answer (score -1):

Hey what are you try to don in this line ?

```
_('Signup opens %s', $this->signups_opening_date);
```

if you try to combine text with date try do like this below

```
"Signup opens $this->signups_opening_date";
```

also you can use sprintf function like below

```
sprintf('Signup opens %s', $this->signups_opening_date)
```

if you try to use laravel language system you can do like this below

```
_('Signup_opens').$this->signups_opening_date;
```

Comment: Thank you Aryan, This did it:             return _("Signup opens $this->signups_opening_date");

Comment: This works too:             return _('Signup_opens ').$this->signups_opening_date;

Comment: This misses the whole point of substitutions in localisation, to handle cases where the word order changes between languages.  Also, "laravel language system" uses `__()`, not `_()` which is [`gettext()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php).

Comment: Well,  
Don't Panic, return __("Signup opens $this->signups_opening_date");  works also.

Comment: Really?  You have a set of translation strings somewhere with every possible date? :-)